# Design quetions - Call web service multiple times within single transaction

Tags: design-patterns, e-commerce

We are building a feature to add multiple gift card in an e-commerce application. The authorization of the gift card is handled by service (which in turn would connect to appropriate vendors). The web service is internal one (withing the company) We are debating about 2 options-

1. Service would take only 1 gift card at a time for authorization
2. Service would be capable to authorizing multiple gift card

Max number of gift card in our application is 6. Choosing approach 1 would mean that the application would have to call the web service(although internal) 6 times during checkout process and I feel it does not look good from a design view.

However, there is another school of thought that choosing option 1 leads to cleaner service interface whereby it performs cohesive operation on a single gift card.

I am leaning more towards option 2 just for design sake(yes - though we also get performance benefit) - since I feel calling the same service multiple times with similar data(gift card is always from same vendor) is  overkill.

Any thoughts on why would we ever want to choose option 1?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend option two.

If you know the system can have 6 gift-cards then build a service that can deal with it. The alternative makes unnecessary network calls, which are inherently "expensive".

Clearly, you'd want the service to cope with a change in the number of gift-cards - don't hard-code the interface to cope with only 6.